# I have a question with the scope of this block

Tags: c, scope

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int var0 = 5;

int main() {
  int var1 = 7;
  int var2 = 9;

  printf("a) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
  {
    int var1 = 17;

    printf("b) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
    var0 = 15;
    var2 = 19;
    printf("c) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
    {
      int var0 = 25;
      printf("d) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
    }
  }
  printf("e) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
}
```

The outcome of the compiler is:

```
a) 5, 7, 9
b) 5, 17, 9
c) 15, 17, 19
d) 25, 17, 19
e) 15, 7, 19
```

I don't understand e. If I'm not mistaken the outerblock has an influence on the inner block however the otherway round this is not the case.So in the case of e only 5 7 and 9 are at the outer block thus in the scope.The compiler gives me for var0 15 which is in the inner blocks and thus not in the scope and the same for var2.
Could you please explain to me my misunderstanding

Comment: You can obviously change the values of outer scope variables from the inner scopes. You couldn't do anything useful if that weren't the case.

Comment: Note, though, that if you declare a new variable of same name within a nested scope the the original variable outside the nested scope gets hidden and isn't accessible any more until you leave this nested scope.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand e.

At `var0 = 15;`, the only declaration of `var0` that is visible is the `int var0 = 5;` declared outside of any function, so the `var0` in `var0 = 15;` refers to that initial `var0`, and the assignment sets it to 15.

The later `int var0 = 25;` declares a new `var0` that hides the earlier `var0`, and therefore the initialization with 25 does not change the earlier `var0` and leaves it at 15.

The `int var1 = 17;` declares a new `var1` that hides the earlier `var1`, and therefore the initialization with 17 does not change the earlier `var1` and leaves it at 7.

At `var2 = 19;`, the only declaration of `var2` that is visible is the `int var2 = 9;` declared inside `main`, so the `var2` in `var2 = 19;` refers to that earlier `var2`, and the assignment sets it to 19.

Answer (score 1):

Your program's variables are in the following 4 [scopes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope):

1. file scope (i.e. global scope)
2. outer block scope (the scope of the entire function `main`)
3. middle block scope
4. innermost block scope

Your program defines the following variables:

1. `var0` in file scope, initialized to the value `5`
2. `var0` in the innermost block scope, initialized to the value `25`
3. `var1` in the outer block scope, initialized to the value `7`
4. `var1` in the middle block scope, initialized to the value `17`
5. `var2` in the outer block scope, initialized to the value `9`

All five of these variables are distinct, even those that have the same name.

Later in the program, you change the value of the variable #1 to `15` and the value of the variable #5 to `19`. Changing the value of variable #1 has no effect on the (future) value of variable #2, because, as previously stated, variables #1 and #2 are distinct, despite them having the same name.

The line

```
var0 = 15;
```

will overwrite the value of the existing variable `var0` with the value `15`, whereas the line

```
int var0 = 25;
```

will define a new variable `var0` which "shadows" the name of the existing variable `var0`, so that all references to the name `var0` in that scope and its nested child scopes refer to the new variable. That makes the old variable `var0` no longer directly accessible in those scopes. (However, the old variable is still indirectly accessibly in those scopes, via a pointer.)

The line

```
printf("e) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
```

will print the variables #1, #3 and #5.

As previously stated, the variable #1 gets initialized to the value `5`, but later gets changed to the value `15`. Since this change has happened before the `printf` line is executed, the `printf` line will print `15` for the value of the variable #1.

As previously stated, the variable #3 gets initialized to the value `7`. It is not changed afterwards. Therefore, the `printf` line will print `7` for the value of the variable #3.

As previously stated, the variable #5 gets initialized to the value `9`, but later gets changed to the value `19`. Since this change has happened before the `printf` line is executed, the `printf` line will print `19` for the value of the variable #5.

Therefore, the quoted `printf` line will print the following:

```
e) 15, 7, 19
```

> If I'm not mistaken the outerblock has an influence on the inner block however the otherway round this is not the case.

This statement is incorrect. It is the other way around. But, as previousy mentioned, this influence is limited due to the names of variables of the inner scope shadowing the names of variables of the outer scope.

The variables of the inner nested scopes [do not exist](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/lifetime) at the time the outer scope is executed. It is not possible to access variables that do not yet exist or whose lifetime has already ended.

---

Side note: If the behavior of variable names shadowing the names of other variables is not desirable, then you may want to consider configuring your compiler to emit a warning when such shadowing occurs. For example, on gcc and clang, you can use the `-Wshadow` command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm not mistaken the outerblock has an influence on the inner block however the otherway round this is not the case.

You are mistaken. There's no such rule. Influence works both ways.

> So in the case of e only 5 7 and 9 are at the outer block thus in the scope. The compiler gives me for var0 15 which is in the inner blocks and thus not in the scope and the same for var2.

The blocks don't matter for access. They matter for "scope". Scope, like a sniper scope, defines which variables you can see. When you can see them, you can change them.

When you define another var1 inside your scope, it *obscures* the outer one. So `var1` in outer scope means "outer var1" and `var1` in inner scope means "inner var1". You can's see the outer var1 because the inner var1 stands in your way.

This is called "[variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)".

To understand this, rename variables to remove name conflict:

```
int var0 = 5;

int main () {
    int var1 = 7;
    int var2 = 9;

    printf("a) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
    {
        int var1a = 17;

        printf("b) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1a, var2);
        var0 = 15;
        var2 = 19;
        printf("c) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1a, var2);
        {
            int var0a = 25;
            printf("d) %d, %d, %d\n", var0a, var1a, var2);
        }
    }
    printf("e) %d, %d, %d\n", var0, var1, var2);
}
```

The inner variables don't exist in outer scopes, but the outer variables exist in inner scopes.